# Angular: Using a method to fill an @Input value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-template, angular-changedetection

Why does the method `getDayShifts(day)` in a parent component's template gets called every time the mouse hovers over a child component?

**abstract.class.ts**

```
export abstract class DayView implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dl.shifts
        .pipe( 
            takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
            map( shifts => this.shifts = shifts),
            tap( shifts => this.filterShifts())
        )
        .subscribe();
  }

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.filterShifts();
    this.afterChanges(changes);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  public abstract afterChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)

  public getDayShifts( day: CalendarDay ): Array<Shift> {
    const s = this.views.getDayShifts(day.date, this.filteredShifts);
    return s;
  }

  /** ... */

}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'day-month-view',
    templateUrl: './day-month-view.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DayMonthViewComponent extends DayView {
    public afterChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {}
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let week of weeks; index as _wi">
   <div *ngFor="let day of week; index as _di">

     <dropdown-btn
            [id]="'dd_'+_wi+'_'+_di"
            [isEnabled]="isEditable(day.date)"
            [options]="dayOptions"
THIS ONE => [objectData]="getDayShifts(day)"
            (selected)="onOptionClick($event)"><span class="day-date">{{day.date.getDate()}}</span></dropdown-btn>
     <shift-month
            [day]="day"
THIS ONE => [shifts]="getDayShifts(day)"></shift-month>
   </div>
</div>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'shift-month',
    templateUrl: './shift-month.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ShiftMonthComponent extends ShiftView {
    public afterInit() {
        const dayShifts = this.views.getDayShifts(this.day.date, this.shifts);
        this.filteredShifts = this.setViewMeta(dayShifts);
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
    }
}
```

**child.abstract.class.ts**

```
export abstract class ShiftView implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

    public ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.afterInit();
    }

    public abstract afterInit()
}
```

Will it always trigger a change for an `@Input()` if it is a method? I am somewhat lost.

Comment: Do you have `mouseover` listeners on your child component?

Comment: No, but click and focusout, template-style

Comment: Can you try creating a stackblitz demo? I tried reproducing it, but can't get it to work on just mouse hover: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfiwdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it happens because method can change value any time, so to make sure correct value is there, angular call it during each re-render. Thats why calling method inside template is bad practice.

Still if you want to do it use OnPush strategy inside component decorator. But with that you might need to trigger change detection manually at some places. Best will be if you can get rid of method call in template and instead pass a simple property.

Comment: Ok, this definitely helped the performance, so +1 for that. It didn't make any difference on the problem though and the solution was to move `detectChanges()` call of `ChangeDetectionRef` directly to the method which appends an html element (not shown in the code) and not to the method which calls this very method (I hope I've made the explanation completely unbearable now). Anyway... avoid methods within `@Input()` params in the templates!